# How to select an item in a listbox in grails

Tags: grails

My book has a publisher.

```
Class Book {
   Publisher publisher
}
```

My book controller has the create action like the following

```
def create() {
        respond new Book(params)
}
```

The create.gsp will display the list of Publishers in the listbox for me to pick

```
<f:all bean="book"/>
```

I put a publisher id in the params before I pass it to the gsp.

```
def create() {
   params.publisherId = 123
   respond new Book(params)
}
```

What code do I type in the create.gsp to select publisher 123 in the publisher listbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chang code in your action to

```
def create() {
   params["publisher.id"] = 123
   respond new Book(params)
}
```

Comment: It works!!!!  Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily a problem, but be aware that the way this code snippet is written, `new Book(params)` is going to result in a query to the database.